# Extract data from python dictionary which created from xml data

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have the following Nornir script that uses Netconf to get data from a router device. The return data is XML.

```
from nornir import InitNornir
from nornir.core.task import Task
from nornir_utils.plugins.functions import print_result
import xmltodict
import pprint

from nornir_netconf.plugins.tasks import netconf_get_config


nr = InitNornir("config.yml")

nr = nr.filter()

def nc_netconf_get_config(task):
    response = task.run(
        netconf_get_config,
        source="running",
        path="""
        <configure xmlns="urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf">
            <router>
                <router-name>Base</router-name>
                <interface></interface>
            </router>
        </configure>
        """,
        filter_type="subtree",
    )
    return response.result.rpc.data_xml

def main():
    result = nr.run(task=nc_netconf_get_config)
    print_result(result)
    result_dict = xmltodict.parse(str(result['test_rtr'][0]))
    print(result_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the returned data in XML format and also the same data converted using xmltodict, as shown above.

From the result_dict (data that has been transformed to python dictionary), I would like to extract the value contained in the 'address', which is '1.1.1.1'.
How do I access this from the dictionary, I have tried various combinations but I cannot access this value.

```
nc_netconf_get_config***********************************************************
* test_rtr ** changed : False **************************************************
vvvv nc_netconf_get_config ** changed : False vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv INFO
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:2fb1bbc1-4f4a-4582-a610-1ad9ce091955">
    <data>
        <configure xmlns="urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf" xmlns:nokia-attr="urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:attributes">
            <router>
                <router-name>Base</router-name>
                <interface>
                    <interface-name>system</interface-name>
                    <ipv4>
                        <primary>
                            <address>1.1.1.1</address>
                            <prefix-length>32</prefix-length>
                        </primary>
                    </ipv4>
                </interface>
            </router>
        </configure>
    </data>
</rpc-reply>
---- netconf_get_config ** changed : False ------------------------------------- INFO
RpcResult(rpc=<ncclient.xml_.NCElement object at 0xffff7f3f14b0>)
^^^^ END nc_netconf_get_config ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{'rpc-reply': {'@xmlns': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0', '@message-id': 'urn:uuid:2fb1bbc1-4f4a-4582-a610-1ad9ce091955', 'data': {'configure': {'@xmlns': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf', '@xmlns:nokia-attr': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:attributes', 'router': {'router-name': 'Base', 'interface': {'interface-name': 'system', 'ipv4': {'primary': {'address': '1.1.1.1', 'prefix-length': '32'}}}}}}}}
```

I would like to get the '1.1.1.1' value from the following dictionary (this is the result_dict variable in the code above):

```
{'rpc-reply': {'@xmlns': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0', '@message-id': 'urn:uuid:2fb1bbc1-4f4a-4582-a610-1ad9ce091955', 'data': {'configure': {'@xmlns': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf', '@xmlns:nokia-attr': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:attributes', 'router': {'router-name': 'Base', 'interface': {'interface-name': 'system', 'ipv4': {'primary': {'address': '1.1.1.1', 'prefix-length': '32'}}}}}}}}
```

Now I have following dictionary:

```
{'rpc-reply': {'@message-id': 'urn:uuid:e71eff55-5e70-4c18-b6fb-c1426328ced7',
               '@xmlns': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0',
               'data': {'configure': {'@xmlns': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf',
                                      '@xmlns:nokia-attr': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:attributes',
                                      'router': {'interface': [{'interface-name': 'system',
                                                                'ipv4': {'primary': {'address': '1.1.1.1',
                                                                                     'prefix-length': '32'}}},
                                                               {'interface-name': 'rtr1',
                                                                'ipv4': {'unnumbered': {'system': None}},
                                                                'port': '10'},
                                                               {'interface-name': 'rtr2',
                                                                'ipv4': {'unnumbered': {'system': None}},
                                                                'port': '20'},
                                                               {'interface-name': 'rtr3',
                                                                'ipv4': {'primary': {'address': '192.168.1.2',
                                                                                     'prefix-length': '30'}},
                                                                'port': '30'},
                                                               {'interface-name': 'rtr4',
                                                                'ipv4': {'primary': {'address': '192.168.2.2',
                                                                                     'prefix-length': '30'}},
                                                                'port': '40'},
                                                               {'interface-name': 'rtr5',
                                                                'ipv4': {'unnumbered': {'system': None}},
                                                                'port': '50'},
                                                               {'interface-name': 'rtr6',
                                                                'ipv4': {'unnumbered': {'system': None}},
                                                                'port': '60'}],
                                                                'router-name': 'Base'}}}}}
```

Comment: `data['rpc-reply']['data']['configure']['router']['interface']['ipv4']['primary']['address']`, This is assuming that entire dictionary is called `data`. If the dictionary's format is inconsistent this can very easily break, depending on expected input it may be more reliable to recursively look through the values in the dictionary until you find a value with an Ipv4 address format, or until you find the `ipv4` key after which getting to the address is easier.

Comment: as a side note, for things like nested dictionaries if you want an easier way to look at how they are nested you can use `pprint`. It's not perfect but it does make it a lot easier.

Comment: result_dict['rpc-reply']['data']['configure']['router']['interface']['ipv4']['primary']['address'], this worked thanks, the dictionary is called result_dict. I would like to understand, how come @xmlns other fields before 'data' is not required to get to the address field.

Comment: So it's not required because they are not part of the nested dictionary that you want's path. `result_dict['rpc-reply']` has the keys `@xmlns`, `@message-id`, and `data`. Of those, the one which has a dictionary value is `data`, and if multiple had a dictionary as a value you would need to see which would eventually contain the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to get value from a nested dict

```
def key_chain(data, *args, default=None): 
    for key in args:
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            data = data.get(key, default)
        elif isinstance(data, (list, tuple)) and isinstance(key, int):
            try:
                data = data[key]
            except IndexError:
                return default
        else:
            return default
    return data
```

You should just call

```
key_chain(result_dict, "rpc-reply", "data", "configure", "router", "interface", "ipv4", "primary", "primary")
```

More examples https://gist.github.com/yaznahar/26bd3442467aff5d126d345cca0efcad

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse the given xml directly to catch the values:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import re

tree = ET.parse("nmap.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

device = []
for elem in root.iter():
    #print(elem.tag, elem.text)
    if elem.tag == "{urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf}router-name":
        router_name = elem.text
    if elem.tag == "{urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf}interface-name":
        interface_name = elem.text
    if elem.tag == "{urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf}address":
        address = elem.text
    if elem.tag == "{urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf}prefix-length":
        prefix_length = elem.text
        row = [router_name, interface_name, address, prefix_length]
        device.append(row)

columns=["router-name","interface-name","address","prefix-length"]
df = pd.DataFrame(device, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

Output, can aslo writen as csv with `.to_csv()`:

```
  router-name interface-name  address prefix-length
0        Base         system  1.1.1.1            32
```

**Option2:**

```
import json
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

thisdict = {'rpc-reply': {'@xmlns': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0', '@message-id': 'urn:uuid:2fb1bbc1-4f4a-4582-a610-1ad9ce091955', 'data': {'configure': {'@xmlns': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf', '@xmlns:nokia-attr': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:attributes', 'router': {'router-name': 'Base', 'interface': {'interface-name': 'system', 'ipv4': {'primary': {'address': '1.1.1.1', 'prefix-length': '32'}}}}}}}}

print("Json Dictioanry:")
#pprint(json.dumps(thisdict))
pp.pprint(thisdict)

routerAddress = thisdict["rpc-reply"]["data"]["configure"]["router"]["interface"]["ipv4"]["primary"]["address"]
print("Router address:",routerAddress)

prefix_length = thisdict["rpc-reply"]["data"]["configure"]["router"]["interface"]["ipv4"]["primary"]["prefix-length"]
print("Prefix length:",prefix_length)

interface_name = thisdict["rpc-reply"]["data"]["configure"]["router"]["interface"]["interface-name"]
print("Interface name:",interface_name)

router_name = thisdict["rpc-reply"]["data"]["configure"]["router"]["router-name"]
print("Router name:",router_name)
```

Output:

```
Json Dictioanry:
{   'rpc-reply': {   '@message-id': 'urn:uuid:2fb1bbc1-4f4a-4582-a610-1ad9ce091955',
                     '@xmlns': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0',
                     'data': {   'configure': {   '@xmlns': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf',
                                                  '@xmlns:nokia-attr': 'urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:attributes',
                                                  'router': {   'interface': {   'interface-name': 'system',
                                                                                 'ipv4': {   'primary': {   'address': '1.1.1.1',
                                                                                                            'prefix-length': '32'}}},
                                                                'router-name': 'Base'}}}}}
Router address: 1.1.1.1
Prefix length: 32
Interface name: system
Router name: Base
```